# How to create a polygon from a CSV file with coordinates using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, convert, csv, pyqgis-3

I like a write a script which:

1. Imports a CSV file that contains a series of points (latitude and longitude) into QGIS

| Lat | Long |
| --- | --- |
| 56.99181358 | -111.4801108 |
| 56.98924901 | -111.4764563 |
| 56.98591437 | -111.471848 |
| 56.98195783 | -111.4725851 |
| 56.98184493 | -111.4796676 |
| 56.98629477 | -111.4847629 |

Here are the points when I import them into the QGIS. I want to create one polygon using these points.

[image]

2. Create a polygon from imported points and finally create a shapefile.

Here is how I did part 1:

```
uri = "file:///C:/Users/katala/Desktop/PyQGIS/Tailings Pond 1A.csv?encoding=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&crs=%s" % ("UTF-8",",", "Lat", "Long","epsg:4326")

#Make a vector layer
eq_layer=QgsVectorLayer(uri,"eq-data","delimitedtext")

#Check if layer is valid
if not eq_layer.isValid():
    print ("Layer not loaded")

#Add CSV data    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(eq_layer)
```

But I don't know how to do the second part and create a polygon. I found the following code, but I don't know how to adjust it to read the points from the generated vector layer.

```
polygon.setToGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([**p_points**]),None)
```

Comment: I added the sample data to the question

Comment: Please add the data as formatted text. Currently there is no way to copy it without typing it out, and it is unlikely anyone will do that. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) for how to create a table in your question (or use an online converter such as https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Comment: Thanks @Matt . I added data as formatted text.

Comment: @BERA it's actually one polygon. I added the points to my question for clarification. If start and end points must be the same to create the polygon I can copy the first point to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the attributes into a list of QGSPointXY's using getFeatures :

```
points = [QgsPointXY(f['long'], f['lat']) for f in iface.activeLayer().getFeatures()]
poly = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([points]) #Create a polygon geometry

#Create a empty memory layer
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326&index=yes", "myLayer", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()

newfeature = QgsFeature()
newfeature.setGeometry(poly)
provider.addFeature(newfeature)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

(Nevermind my comment that a polygon has to start and stop in the same coordinate: [Note that unlike some programs, QGIS will close the ring for you so there is no need to duplicate the first point as the last.](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/geometry.html#geometry-construction))

[image]