# Extract points coordinates from vector layer in a standalone PyQGIS script in Ubuntu

Tags: python, pyqgis, ubuntu, linux

I am running a PyQGIS script (QGIS 2.18.17) on the Ubuntu terminal to import the following CSV file that includes latitude and longitude of several points and create a polygon from them.

| Lat | Long |
| --- | --- |
| 56.99181358 | -111.4801108 |
| 56.98924901 | -111.4764563 |
| 56.98591437 | -111.471848 |
| 56.98195783 | -111.4725851 |
| 56.98184493 | -111.4796676 |
| 56.98629477 | -111.4847629 |

I can import the CSV file as a vector layer, but I don't know how to extract the coordinates of the points and create the polygon from them (I wrote a similar script in the PyQGIS console in the windows version, and I used the iface.activeLayer() to select the active layer and read points coordinates ([How to create a polygon from a CSV file with coordinates using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/425603/how-to-create-a-polygon-from-a-csv-file-with-coordinates-using-pyqgis)). But iface does not work in the standalone script and I don't know how to do it).

Here is the script in Ubuntu:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,os,glob
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Put your pyqgis code here:
uri = "file:////home/aka000/site4/PyQGIS/Tailings_Pond_1A.csv?encoding=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&crs=%s" % ("UTF-8",",", "Lat", "Long","epsg:4326")

#Make a vector layer
eq_layer=QgsVectorLayer(uri,"eq-data","delimitedtext")

#Check if layer is valid
if not eq_layer.isValid():
    print ("Layer not loaded")

#Add CSV data    
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(eq_layer)

idx=eq_layer.getFeatures()

for f in idx:
    point=QgsPointXY(f['long'], f['lat'])
```

And this is the error I get:

```
point=QgsPointXY(f['long'], f['lat'])
NameError: name 'QgsPointXY' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to add `from qgis.core import QgsPointXY` to your imports.

Comment: Hi @Matt, thanks for your comment. I added it but I get this error: ImportError: cannot import name QgsPointXY

Comment: It looks like QgsPointXY is not part of the QGIS 2.x API. Are you translating a QGIS 3.x script?

Comment: @Matt Yes, you are right. I downloaded the PyQGIs developer cookbook 2.18 and there is no QgsPointXY in that. There is only QgsPoint. And to answer your question, yes, I am translating the PyQGIS script I wrote on QGIs 3.x in windows. So in this case, is there an alternative function for QgsPointXY? I want to reads the points coordinates after I import the csv and create a polygon from them.

Comment: QgsPoint should work

Comment: Yes @Matt, thanks. I don't know why I used QgsPointXY in the beginning, but QGSPoint works well.